# What does the double underscore in Scala imports mean?

Tags: scala, playframework

Say you're importing a library like so:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{__, Writes }
```

What does the double underscore do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JsPath is a core building block for creating Reads/Writes. JsPath represents the location of data in a JsValue structure. You can use the JsPath object (root path) to define a JsPath child instance by using syntax similar to traversing JsValue:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val json = { ... }

// Simple path
val latPath = JsPath \ "location" \ "lat"

// Recursive path
val namesPath = JsPath \\ "name"

// Indexed path
val firstResidentPath = (JsPath \ "residents")(0)
```

The play.api.libs.json package defines an alias for JsPath: __ (double underscore). You can use this if you prefer:

val longPath = __ \ "location" \ "long"

Comment: Is this alias `__` no longer available in play 2.6? I am getting Not Found error even after importing `play.api.libs.json._`

Answer (score 5):

it is an import of a value from package object json:

```
package object json {

  /**
   * Alias for `JsPath` companion object
   */
  val __ = JsPath

}
```

Comment: Do you know if this is just play nomenclature or a Scala thing as well?

Comment: Nothing in the language, not even customary, just that two underscores make a valid identifier (while a single underscore is a keyword)